# How to add a SpotLight to Camera with ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

**`Three.js r105`**

I'm trying to add a `SpotLight` to the camera to give it a "Flashlight" effect. Although, it seems the light stops working all-together once I add the `SpotLight` to my `Camera`. What am I doing wrong?

Weird, as the `LightHelper` looks to be working fine. Also, adding the `SpotLight` independently to the `Scene` works fine.

Once I attach the `SpotLight` to the `Camera`, there is no shred of even the smallest flicker of light

```
const cameraLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 4, 40);
cameraLight.castShadow = true;

cameraLight.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
cameraLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
cameraLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.far = 500;

var d = 32;

cameraLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;

cameraLight.visible = true;
cameraLight.distance = 40;
cameraLight.decay = 1;
cameraLight.angle = Math.PI/2;
cameraLight.penumbra = 0.1;

camera.add( cameraLight );
cameraLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1);
cameraLight.target = camera;    

var cameraLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( cameraLight, 5, 0x00ff00 );
scene.add( cameraLightHelper );

scene.add( camera );
```

[image]

Comment: If `camera` is not a part of scene graph, it itself and its children won't be counted by renderer. Try add the camera with the light source to the scene: `scene.add(camera)`

Comment: Have a look at this forum post: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/mesh-points-to-the-camera-on-only-2-axis-with-shaders/21555/10

Comment: @prisoner849 I do already have the camera added to scene :( Provided code is just a snippet. If I add a `SpotLight` without attaching to the camera, it works fine which is weird

Comment: @prisoner849 added an image preview. The green lines are via `var cameraLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( cameraLight, 5, 0x00ff00 ); ` &&  `scene.add( cameraLightHelper );` -- Also, I'm using `OrbitControls`, could that perhaps somehow be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of hair pulling, this is the code that made it work

```
const cameraLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 6);
cameraLight.castShadow = true;


cameraLight.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
cameraLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512/4 * renderer.capabilities.maxTextures; // default
cameraLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512/4 * renderer.capabilities.maxTextures; // default
cameraLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1; // default
cameraLight.shadow.camera.far = 500; // default

var d = 32;

cameraLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
cameraLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;

cameraLight.visible = true;
cameraLight.distance = 40;
cameraLight.decay = 1;
cameraLight.angle = Math.PI/4;
cameraLight.penumbra = 0.1; 
    
camera.add( cameraLight );
cameraLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1);
scene.add( camera );
cameraLight.target = camera;
```

Basically the same thing..

I did clear up my cache, so that could've been the issue? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Spotlight, I recommend [you use a `SpotlightHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/SpotLightHelper), not a PointlightHelper.

You have to make sure your `Spotlight` is added to the `Scene`. Keep in mind that an object can only have **one** parent. So adding a light to the scene, then adding it to the camera removes it from the scene.

```js
// This adds spotlight to scene
scene.add(spotlight);

// This removes spotlight from scene, and adds to camera
camera.add(spotlight);
```

So if you haven't added your camera to the scene, then the light won't be rendered. You can fix this with nesting one inside the other:

```js
camera.add(spotlight);
scene.add(camera);
```

Now the light is the "grandchild" of the scene, and it will render. Just make sure your spotlight is facing in the same direction as the camera. You might have it pointing backwards or something, and you'll never see the cone of light. Using `Spotlighthelper` should help you figure out which way it's pointing.

Answer (score -2):

- Which camera type has a "add" method ?
- The PointLightHelper accepts a PointLight as first argument.

[image]

Comment: Every `Object3D` [has an .add() method](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add). The Camera is a subclass of Object3D, so it inherits this method.